# how to make two content in middle of the page and below the content another text with bracket?

Tags: html, css

```css
#wrap {
    background: #e7e7e7;
    padding: 4%;
    text-align: center;
    width: 70%;
}

#left, #right {
     background: #ccc;
     display: inline-block;
     padding: 7%;
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
 <div id="wrap">
    <span id="left" class="cer" style="">asfsdfsfdsf</span>   
    <span  id="right" class="cer"  style="">fsfsdfsf</span>
    </div>
```

i want to make a two contents in middle page and below the content i need to mention bracket content.How to create a div?

It should be middle of the page

looking for like this

```
sometext         anothertext
--------         -----------
(orgin)           (grade)



<div id="wrap">
<span id="left" class="cer" style="">a</span>   
<span  id="right" class="cer"  style="">b</span>
</div>


#wrap {
   
    padding: 1%;
    text-align: center;
    width: 80%;
}
```

Comment: Can you share the HTML and CSS code you have tried to accomplish this with?

Comment: yes i will share

Comment: Please use a Stack Snippet (icon looks like `<>` in the editor toolbar) for the code that you've tried. It's currently unclear whether the code presented is your attempt or part of the example.

Comment: @HereticMonkey plz check it now

Comment: @HereticMonkey i have to add that content be underline and below the underline (orgin) and second content be underline and below with (grade)

Comment: I'm not sure how you expect to get  "sometext / (orgin)" and "anothertext / (grade)" out of "asfsdfsfdsf" and "fsfsdfsf"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done easily using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Your desired structure has a row with 2 columns, where each column has 3 lines of text. So you can try something like this below:

```css
#left, #right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px;
}

#wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="left" class="cer" style="">
    <p>sometext</p>
    <p>-----</p>
    <p>(orgin)</p>
  </div>
  
  <div id="right" class="cer"  style="">
    <p>anothertext</p>
    <p>-----</p>
    <p>(grade)</p>
  </div>
</div>
```